# In the Beatles' "I'm So Tired", why is Sir Walter Raleigh "such a stupid git"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, the-beatles

In The Beatles' *White Album* song "I'm So Tired", one of the verses has the following lyrics:

> I'm so tired, I'm feeling so upset
> Although I'm so tired, I'll have another cigarette
> **And curse Sir Walter Raleigh**
> **He was such a stupid git**

My question is, why was Sir Walter Raleigh "a stupid git"? I only know him as a poet, so I'm assuming this is some kind of reference to one of his works?

Comment: I assume the reference to poetry is a mix-up with Sir Walter Scott...?

Comment: @Lefty no. They are two different people.

Comment: Yes, I know! They weren't even contemporaries - they were born 200 years apart. I was pointing it out because your question is wrong to talk about Walter Raleigh as being a poet.

Comment: Except Walter Raleigh was a poet. Both Walter Raleigh and Walter Scott were poets.

Comment: OK, he wrote poetry - I wasn't aware of that. I doubt that many people are. He certainly isn't regarded as a notable person from history due to his poetry. Whereas Walter Scott is well known as a poet even to those of us who know nothing about poetry.

Comment: Sounds like you learned something new then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Sir Walter Raleigh](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/historic_figures/raleigh_walter.shtml) is credited as the one who introduced tobacco to the UK from the (then) colony of Virginia. So the reference is to the cigarette in the lyrics, and the love-hate relationship with smoking that the character in the song and John Lennon the writer of the song both had. There's a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/beatles/comments/xichp/what_does_the_line_and_curse_sir_walter_raleigh/) on this theme.

At the time of writing the song, John was 3 weeks into a stay in India where the band were studying meditation, according to this other [reference](https://www.beatlesbible.com/songs/im-so-tired/),. The reference also quotes this from Lennon from David Sheff's 'All we are saying' : "I'm So Tired was me, in India again. I couldn't sleep, I'm meditating all day and couldn't sleep at night. The story is that. One of my favorite tracks. I just like the sound of it, and I sing it well."

Answer (score 2):

This [reference](http://www.beatlesebooks.com/im-so-tired) provides the most plausible explanation for the reference to Raleigh. It explains the evolution of Lennon's lyric. An original lyric was:

> Although I choked, I'll have another cigarette, and blame Sir Walter Raleigh

The lyric was then worked on to scan and to provide a rhyme with "upset" and "cigarette" .

Answer (score -2):

I think he said “get”. Kind of British for wooing a woman.
The song is about a woman, not cigarettes.
I have zero evidence.
I did just listen to it again though.
Oh, and it rhymes.

Comment: a "git" is an idiot..  they did not make a mistake it wasnt "Get"
also listen to the line directly before walter raleigh was defined as a stupid git.
Ill have another cigarette,...